# Storing fibonacci values

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, fibonacci

I did a very simple solution to fibonacci:

```
(defn fib [n]
  (if (or (zero? n) (= n 1))
    1
    (+ (fib (dec n)) (fib (- n 2)))))
```

but instead of returning the value, for example

```
(fib 6) ; 13
```

I would return the sequence 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13... I was thinking about store the values in a sequence, but where should I return the sequence? I mean, verifying if I'm at the last call of fib does not sound much nice.

ps: I'm trying to solve this exercise: https://www.4clojure.com/problem/26

Answer (score 0):

Clojure functions return the result of the last evaluated form. You could accumulate your Fibonacci numbers in a vector.

Answer (score 0):

A nice lazy version of fibonacci is:

```
(def lazy-fib
 "Lazy sequence of fibonacci numbers"
  ((fn rfib [a b]
    (lazy-seq (cons a (rfib b (+' a b)))))
   0 1))
```

Then you can use it with:

```
(fn [n] (take n lazy-fib))
```

Which gives, after some formatting for this problem:

```
(fn[n] 
 (drop 1 (take (inc n) ((fn rfib [a b]
  (lazy-seq (cons a (rfib b (+' a b)))))
    0 1))))
```